# <a> with glyphicon in bootstrap carousel stacking on top of each other, how do I remove this behaviour?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two `<a>` links with glyphicons and they are stacking on top of each other, I want to remove this behaviour, make them show side to side.

Here's a fiddle of it:

https://jsfiddle.net/9h1k2pta/1/

Code of the two `<a>`s.

```
<div class="carousel-control"
    style="bottom:auto; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;
    right:0;">
        <a href="#slideshow" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"
                style="font-size: 50px;"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#slideshow" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"
                style="font-size: 50px;"></span>

            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
```

Yes, my HTML has styles in it, not beautiful, blah. It's just a test.

I want to show them as regular arrows: < >   not as they are showing now. How can I do this? I've tried removing inherited styles in Chrome and still couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind. I managed to do it.

Apparently bootstrap has a rule specific for each chevron in a carousel-control and it has margins:

```
.carousel-control .icon-next, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
       right: 50%;
       margin-right: -10px;
```

}

So i just overrode it with:

```
div.carousel-control > a > span.glyphicon-chevron-left {
    margin-left: -40px;
```

}